# Does Kafka has one partition and one channel, and one channel corresponds to the processing of one thread？

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, apache-kafka

is there one partition and one channel in Kafka, and one channel corresponds to the processing of one thread?

I want to know is there a case of such implementation in .NET or .NETCore?

It may be like this follwing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWL5Y.png)

Whether this design is reasonable, welcome to discuss it with me,

But I don't know how to achieve it？

Comment: If some seniors have done it, I hope to give some guidance;
If anyone knows a similar implementation, please give me some information for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka doesn't have a term called channel.

Topics can have many partitions. Consumers within the same consumer group cannot consume from the same partition. Consumers often correspond 1:1 from threads to partitions

Comment: You're right, but I means the channel belongs to netocre,  under the namespace of  "System.Threading.Channels",  I encountered some difficulties about how to implement a one consume thread for one partition, and the unbounded channel only store the data of this partition, and the consume thread fetch data from the channel.

Comment: For C#, is there a corresponding implementation for some reference?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to ask. Start here https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet